# How to share YouTube video and audio on Google Meet

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, video-streaming, google-meet

I'd like to be able to share a YouTube video during a Google Meet, with audio, high resolution, & minimal latency.

Is this possible / what's the best way to accomplish that?

**Things that don't work / no longer work**:

- Google chrome allows you to **Cast** [image] your browser. However, in order to make your meeting an eligible cast target, you need to [**Enable Cloud Services**](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6320939?hl=en#zippy=%2Cto-set-up-casting-to-cloud-services-like-hangouts-or-cast-for-education-from-chrome) which seems to be unofficially discontinued. Example in [How to Share video withAudio in Google Meet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xui69IphEo)
- There is native support for **Docs, Sheets, and Slides** which all offer the ability to [**Present to a Meeting**](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308856#present_apps) [image], but nothing similar for videos

Answer (score 0):

Google has released the ability to [**Present high-quality video and audio in Google Meet**](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/04/high-quality-video-audio-meet.html)

> You can now share higher-quality video with audio content in a Meet video call. You can do this through a new present a Chrome tab feature. Now, when you use this feature with video content playing, everyone in the meeting will see and hear the video and audio being shared.

1. Open Google Meet in one tab and the desired Video in another.
2. Select the present option and choose "A Tab"

   [image: Present > A Tab]
3. Choose the tab you want to share and make sure "share tab audio" is checked

   [image: Share a Tab]
4. **Note**: The [default view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMB9F.png), [theater mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzWvE.png), and even [full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3n86.png) mode leave a lot of extra unused and potentially distracting space.  I'd recommend using the [embed URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUH6m.png) with [extra query parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) instead:

   - **Default**: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU`
   - **Embed**: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VgC4b9K-gYU?modestbranding=1&rel=0`

**See Also**: [How to share video along with audio on Google Meet](https://www.gadgetsnow.com/how-to/how-to-share-video-along-with-audio-on-google-meet/articleshow/83929444.cms)